# Cant use JsonResponse in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, ascii, utf

I have a bunch of values which I would like to send from `views.py` function to my template in Django. I saw some topics that the best way is by `json` format. So I did so. But because my values are not `ascii` I'm using a upgraded version which worked in normal `Http response` but don't work in `JSON response`.

Here is my code

```py
base = {weather_main_key : weather_main_values, wind_speed_key : wind_speed_value + "m", wind_deg_key : wind_deg_value, base_temp_key : base_temp_value + " ℃", base_press_key : base_press_value + " mbar", base_hum_key : base_hum_value + " % " }
        base = json.dumps(base, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
        return JsonResponse(json.dumps(base))
```

So I had an error msg

```
In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False.
```

So I did as it told me

```py
JsonResponse(json.dumps(base, safe=False, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8'))
```

And now the error is

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'safe'
```

And I can't move...

Comment: The main idea of a `JsonResponse` is that it will do the serialization for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoah, *triple* encoding. Why are you doing that?

You serialize to json. Then, inside the call to JsonResponse, you serialize to json again. But JsonResponse itself does serialization, so you've serialized three times.

Stop that; just pass the dict to JsonResponse.

```
base = {weather_main_key : weather_main_values, wind_speed_key : wind_speed_value + "m", wind_deg_key : wind_deg_value, base_temp_key : base_temp_value + " ℃", base_press_key : base_press_value + " mbar", base_hum_key : base_hum_value + " % " }
return JsonResponse(base)
```

Comment: btw. How could I access that data from html page? I'm sending it to urls like `path('test/', views.weathere, name='weather'),` but, I would like to insert it to my base.html

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. The point of doing this would be to request it via Ajax. If you're not doing that, you don't need a separate view and response at all.

Comment: So I could normally download it via Ajax script in base.html?